# Why BinaryFormatter is named like tha and not BinarySerializer?

Tags: .net, serialization

I am new to serialization. I have a silly question:
Why BinaryFormatter is named like BinaryFormatter and not BinarySerializer?

To be more specific why isn't it called BinarySerializer if it is doing serialization ? What else does it do other than serialization of data, that it should be called a formatter?

Comment: For one, it does deserialization, too.

Comment: But then it should be BinarySerializer .. why formatter?

Answer (score 2):

Why *not*? Why would `BinarySerializer` be a better name?

I wasn't privy to the deliberations of the API design team, but I suspect that it's called a "formatter" because it formats the data retrieved from or pushed out to a byte stream. You use the formatter as a helper object both when serializing and deserializing data.

Note also that there is a [`SoapFormatter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx) that follows the same naming scheme, and both of these classes are defined in the [`System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters`namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.aspx).

Comment: Then why is XmlSerializer not called XmlFormatter?

Comment: Because it does more than just serialization. While it's true that you can format binary data for serialization, you can also format binary data for other purposes. Theoretically at least, the `BinaryFormatter` class does both of those things.

Comment: So u mean it is not always serializing? can you please provide a clear example?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I agree with you - it would have at least been more consistent with `XmlSerializer`, and the (later) `DataContractSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, etc. Perhaps they felt it was different because it was used in remoting, but ultimately what it does is serialization and deserialization.

However: *naming stuff is hard*. Perhaps it is as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks Marc ... Atleast I realise I am not the only one suffering from this confusion ... and as per as my observation about Cody Gray goes he doesnt understand serialization at all, just wrote something for the sake of writing !!

Comment: @user1401198 that's a bit rude (towards Cody), and unnecessary. In many ways the two terms are fairly interchangeable. The naming in this case is merely inconsistent, not strictly incorrect.

Comment: nothing rude ... he is misguiding people ... thats not nice ..